# rest webservice in android

Tags: android

can anybody give example of rest webservice in android

Answer (score 2):

Janusz is correct, but if you want a good intro into how Google envisions REST being used in Android see [this presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE). When you're done follow alexanderblom's link on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297988/developing-android-rest-client-applications).